# Taking the first item from a scaffold on Rails 3

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

I've already do my research but I think I don't know how to ask so I'll try to explain...
Im looking for a way to ask for the first entry saved on a Scaffold... 
Like 
If I have in the table Products:

- Sweeter
- Pants
- Scarf
- Tennis

and I write `@first_prod = Products.first` (or something like that) on my model or in my view `<%= Products.each.first %>` (or something like that) Rails give me the first prouduct in this case - Sweeter...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails you can define a few default ways to get the content from a model.

In your case i would create a scope.

in your model enter the following:

```
scope ordered, :order => "Product.created_at ASC"
```

When you call

```
Product.ordered
```

It will return all your products ordered by when they were created.
If you then want the very first product you just to

```
Product.ordered.first
```

In the case you just want to get the item in one specific place you could do the following (instead of what i mentioned above)

Product.find(:first, :order => 'created_at ASC')

If my explanation is not clear, just let me know and i'll try to refrase

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Let's assume that when you call `Product.all` that it returns the products in the order you've specified above.  So, to get Sweeter, you could call `Product.all.first`.  Or, if in your controller you've done `@products = Product.all` and you want it in your view you can use `@products.first`.  Or if you're looping through them and want to do something special with the first one you could do this:

```
<% @products.each_with_index do |product, i| %>
  <% if id == 0 %>
     do something special as this is the first product
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question, I think...

If you know you want access to the first saved item of a specific model, then you would just call `Product.first`.  So, in the controller action for the view you want to access that data in, just type `@product = Product.first`... for example

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @product = Product.first
end
```

That way you can access the first saved product as well as have access to the entire collection in your index view code.

Comment: the .first method does not necessarily give the first entered element. it give the first element by using the databases default sorting. Im my answer i create queries that use the order_by clause.

Comment: Interesting, I just assumed all databases default sort would be based on the unque id for the record.  If that's not the case then I would recommend going with a scope that orders based on the created_at attribute.

Comment: well, as far as i know mysql default the sorting to time of entering InnoDB sorts by primary key (which does not have to be the ID)
In a lot of the cases .first give you what you expect, but it is good practice not to count on it :)